# Find out processing value when SQL is perfomring a select between two values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have report to generate between two given dates but my calculation for one column should display value only if created date(on that table) is equal to current processing value (I dont know what to call it) of  two given dates(I performing a join here)

Examples

```
TranID OrderID Amount CreatedDate
1          1      200    08/12/2011
2          1      100    08/16/2011
```

Report between 08/12/2011 to 08/15/2011 should display like

```
1      1   200  08/12/2011
2      1    0   08/13/2011
3      1    0   08/14/2011
4      1    0   08/15/2011
```

I cant use case statement in the select it wont work because i am not setting amount 0 not by between statement.

My question may not be clear. Reply if you didn't understand

Comment: Where does "current processing value" come from? I can't see the logic you are using in your desired results. Why does `08/13/2011` have the amount set to 0.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned I don't know what I should call for current processing value. Let me explain it again I want to compare with each date between the give range of values with the created date. If it matches I want to display the value if not I want to say 0

Comment: It makes a bit more sense now you have edited your example data I think, but shouldn't your desired resultset have 4 rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Show result like below, first generate all possible dates in the range using a CTE.

```
Row Amount  CreatedDate
1   200 2011-08-12
2   0   2011-08-13
3   0   2011-08-14
4   0   2011-08-15


CREATE TABLE #temp(TranID INT, OrderID INT,  Amount INT,  CreatedDate date)
INSERT INTO #temp (TranID, OrderID, Amount, CreatedDate) VALUES (1,1,200 ,'08/12/2011')
INSERT INTO #temp (TranID, OrderID, Amount, CreatedDate) VALUES (2,1,100 ,'08/16/2011')


DECLARE @startDate DATE ,@endDate DATE
Select @startDate = '08/12/2011' , @endDate = '08/15/2011'


;WITH Dates (CreatedDate, RowNumber) AS (
    /* Generating all possible dates in the range */
    SELECT @startDate AS CreatedDate, 1 AS RowNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(d,1,CreatedDate), RowNumber+1 FROM dates WHERE CreatedDate < @endDate
)

SELECT RowNumber, Coalesce(sum(t.Amount),0) AS Amount, d.CreatedDate FROM Dates d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp t
ON d.CreatedDate = t.CreatedDate
GROUP BY RowNumber,d.CreatedDate
```